# Getting yarn config from Flink Job

Tags: java, apache-flink, hadoop-yarn

For a pyspark job deployed in a yarn cluster, to access yarn client I can do something like this

```py
conf = sparkSession._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
YarnClient = sparkSession._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.YarnClient
yarn = YarnClient.createYarnClient()
yarn.init(conf)
yarn.start()
```

What is the equivalent of doing this in a Flink job written in Java and deployed with yarn? I am able to create the YarnClient object, but how to get the config?